# Removing an element after a div with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I would like to remove the p tag that directly follows a div using jquery. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="fbcommentbox"></div>
<p>Powered by <a href="http://pleer.co.uk/wordpress/plugins/facebook-comments/">Facebook Comments</a></p>
```

So in this case, all content inside the `<p>` tags will be set to `display:none`.

This seems like it would be VERY simple to do in jquery but I cannot seem to put my finger on it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$('div.fbcommentbox + p').hide();
```

- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) sets `display: none`.
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the element from the DOM.

Pick the one you need.

Comment: @Tomalak, can you explain why `next()` is undesirable? :-)

Comment: @Ben: It's not undesirable as such, but it is slower than the selector (because with this selector, jQuery can make use of `querySelectorAll` which is supported natively by modern browsers). The actual difference is probably negligible in this case, but it's useful to bear that in mind for more complex scenarios.

Comment: For the fun of it I did this performance check between `+` and `.next()`, looks like next is quicker which might make a difference if (for some readon) you've got to traverse the DOM from within a loop. http://jsperf.com/jquery-next-vs-plus

Comment: i tried onclick $(this + 'p').remove() and this deletes all the <p> elements next to myclass.. so i used $(this).next('p').remove() to remove only the one that follows myclass. Just in case someone needs the same functionality...

Answer (score 34):

This should work:

```
$('.fbcommentbox').next('p').remove();
```

We select the div, then use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next element.

Comment: Maybe `.next('p')` would be even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.fbcommentbox').next().hide();` or `$('.fbcommentbox').css('display','none')`.